# Recursively calling a rails Rspec test module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, recursion, rspec

I am very new to TDD in rails. I want to parse a JSON data and recursively call a test on the objects that is built from the hashed JSON data. The JSON data is built in such a way that the same object structure is repeated many times on several branch.

What I wanted to know is, is it possible to call the same test module recursively ? If yes then how can that be done ?

Comment: for what the recursion is required?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution, as I said earlier that I am pretty new to rails. The solution was quite simple.

I created a simple private function inside the test module which could be easly invoked from the test modules.

```
    it "calls a recursive function" do
        recursive_function()
    end

    private
    def recursive_function()
    ...
    end
```